# Make child width equal to parent height with CSS only

Tags: html, css

[image]

As described by the image there are two elements: A parent (dark gray) and child (not so dark gray). The width and height of the parent is fluid. The ratio of the child i 1:1 or y:y where y is equal to the height of the parent.

I've tried to find ways to solve this using flex, calc, padding etc but have reached the end of the road. Any ideas how to solve this with pure CSS are much appreciated.

EDIT: I realize now I should have added more details regarding the usage of this scenario. As well as what I consider to be a dynamic height. Dynamic height for me suggests that the height is decided by the amount of content it contains. So I added some HTML to clarify. The .content div may be unnecessary if you can put the content directly in the .container div. But that depends on how you write the CSS:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    Here is some text. It can be long and it can be short. 
    It will affect the height of the .container thus also 
    the height and width of the .square.
  </div>
  <div class="square">1:1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any code from what you have tried?

Comment: Where is the height of the darker element is coming from?

Comment: So your question is how to make height of element equal to its width if width is dynamic.?

Comment: Can you post the HTML for this?

Comment: @MikeHarrison obviously, HTML for this is `<div><div></div></div>` ;)

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5 fair enough :P

Comment: @Martin_P The height of the darker element is dynamic. It depends on what content is in it.

Comment: The HTML could pretty much be what @Wh1T3h4Ck5 says, with the content directly in the parent. But if you like you could add another child to hold the content `<parent><light-gray></light-gray><content></content></parent>`. Whichever solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible to do what you try!You can't get parents height without JS. But maybe there is another solution. Does your parent container also has a fixed proportion?

Comment: I agree, I don't think this is possible either but I learn new things about CSS everyday, I think most people working with it do. So who knows. The parent container does not have a fixed proportion.

Answer (score 1):

This question was quite old. But today I found a quite-tricky solution that may help. That is, I utilize the property of image (svg here) that preserve the aspect ratio while scaling. So I insert an empty `svg` and make its height fit the parent. Then we have its width equals to its height. (You can change the  `1 1` in the part `<svg viewBox="0 0 1 1" >` to change the ratio).
See the example below. Sorry for my bad English.

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  
  /* This is just for the example */
  width: 700px; /* x */
  height: 100px; /* y */
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

.left {
  flex-grow: 1
  
  /* This is just for the example */
  color: #cddfc9;
  background-color: #636363;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.child {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
}

/* This is the trick */
.child svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.child > .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  
  /* This is just for the example */
  color: white;
  background-color: #8a8a8a;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="left">
   Text of various length be here...
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 1 1" ></svg>
    <div class="content">
      yxy
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the vh property for this. Set the height of your parent div in vh and then use the same vh value for the width of your child div and set the height of the child div to 100%.

```css
#parent{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top:0;
    width: 400px;
    height: 50vh;
    background-color: red;
}

#child{
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50vh;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
   <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i liked this one in theory but when you test it with content in the divs it falls apart http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XNzVaa

Comment: use overflow scroll on the chil element. what you do will fall apart on most css setups. :) and then you can use a webkit to hide the scrollbars.

Comment: As mentioned in the question the height is fluid (maybe I should have written dynamic to be extra clear). 50vh is 50 % of the viewport, thus not a dynamic height.

Comment: so what do you mean by "dynamic"? if you change the height of the window the div wil change. Isnt that dynamic?

Comment: That's dynamic relative to the window. I was thinking dynamic relative to it's content. Let's say the parent contains som text that affects its height, the parents height will increase when more content is added and the child should follow. I realize now I probably could have been much clearer in the question.

Comment: i am sad to say this is impossible with pure css :( But there is good news :) you can do this very easily with a bit of javascript but seeing you dont want to use JS i would suggest looking for a different solution for you problem. maybe the way you want isnt the best idea. Let me know if you need anymore help.